# onclick event is not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Here is the code of Html and Js.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown mobiledropdown " style='width: 30%;'>
    <p class="btn dropdown-toggle mobiledropdownbtn" style='margin: 0;' href="#" 
        role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Sort 
    By</p>
          
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Price:High to Low</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Price:Low to High</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Popularity</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">What's new</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var filter=document.getElementsByClassName('filters')[0];
var btn=document.getElementsByClassName('mobileview')[0];

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(filter.style.display=="none")
        filter.style.display="block";
    else
        filter.style.display="none";
})


var modal3=document.getElementById("myModal3");
       
var btn3=document.getElementById("myBtn3");
var mdb=document.getElementsByClassName("mobiledropdownbtn")[0].onclick=function(){
alert("clicked");
if(filter.style.display=="block")
    filter.style.display="none";
 };
```

This code was working **FINE** with bootstrap CDN 4.4.1 but when I used cdn 5.0.0 this is not working at all.
I have tried every possibility but could not land an answer. Please help.
Code is that there is a filter section and if the button is pressed and the filter section is open then before the dropdown open filter section should be closed. Please help.

Comment: The classes **filters** and **mobileview** are not used in your sample.

Comment: It is just for CSS

Comment: Is that so? Your script begs to differ: `document.getElementsByClassName('filters')[0]` and `document.getElementsByClassName('mobileview')[0]`.

Comment: I noticed that I am unable to trigger on click on that dropdown. If it is a simple p tag it is working.Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: There is no element with id `btn3`

Comment: It looks like you changed your markup without adjusting your script. Also your dropwdown has not click event, that event is on the `p`.